# How to implement this oracle?

Tags: oracles

Suppose I have an oracle $U_f$ that maps $|x\rangle \mapsto (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle$ where $f : \{0,\dots,N\} \to \{0,1\}$ is such that $f(0)=0$. I want to show that I can implement the oracle $|x\rangle|b\rangle \mapsto |x\rangle|b \oplus f(x)\rangle$ using just one application of $U_f$.

I figured a way to do this but by using a controlled version of $U_f$. The following circuit does the trick:

[image: circ]

However what if I don't have access to the controlled version of $U_f$? Can I still do it? Does the fact that $f(0)=0$ help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a temporary ancillary copy conditional on the control, and apply the operation to the copy. This only applies the varying -1 factors if the control is ON, not OFF, which gives the necessary phase kickback.

[Example](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7E941k%22%2C%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22%7Ek8jv%22%2C%22%7Ek8jv%22%2C%22%7Ek8jv%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7Eocnm%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Eqmt4%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7E941k%22%2C%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22%7Ek8jv%22%2C%22%7Ek8jv%22%2C%22%7Ek8jv%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%7Eqmt4%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Eqmt4%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Uf%22%2C%22circuit%22%3A%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ek8jv%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%7C0%3E%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7E941k%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22out%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ed6m1%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22arg%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Eocnm%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Z%5Ef(0)%22%2C%22circuit%22%3A%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Z%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D):

[image]

The $f(0) = 0$ requirement is avoided by classically computing $f(0)$ and applying a $Z$ to the control if it's 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks! It's all clear now!